# What encoding is used on that files?

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I have a XML file that contains symbol files. Example:

```
<Export>
  <File id="1">
     <Hash>d1fdd1b25e6a864558b37a817757cbd0</Hash>
     <Content>H4sIAAAAAAAEAM3USwrCMBAG4L3gHYZZKbQ1GQyBtvEutsY2WGhp4qO3N33pwo3LkASGn4F8TCC5fVTwMPpZtC+FMQe/uQASeNpuAPK71VA2Z2sVFl2H4JskwqCQIRzmll6XbszZmj/NxdUK+RGh1qaqnULydT/2JFL4algr64ZGK7yaponb7lwaN6Q8YdkYpH1V7IiO0XL2mXV9e9NTziK/1iSebkxZIn5QNKHogxJfk1hJ9CHRXyQhouX8QaJfkwzQNM9JBmWSAZrmOfGwHk+GiFomFdbzyWBQ+cH/vKc3CmCcz38FAAA=</Content>
  </File>
</Export>
```

I don't know the file types but I guess it could be SVG. I tried to decode it with base64

```
var result = Convert.FromBase64String(fileContent);
```

but this does not seem to result in anything usable. What encoding was used here?

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to contact an author of that file and ask him/her? Also you can try to save decoded from base64 `Content` to disk and use [file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) tool to determine file type.

Comment: maybe ask whoever sent you the data? @AleksAndreev for me, that says "gzip compressed data, max speed, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)"; looking inside the gzip, it appears to be SVG

Comment: Yes, thats it. It is a GZIP and unzipping it the content makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: The hash is probably a key used to encrypt the data.

Comment: @jdweng no, it is not a ZIP archive - it is *just* a GZIP compessed stream (ZIP is the archive, GZIP is one of the stream compression mechanisms)

Comment: And BTW if I ask the author maybe I get an answer. And if so in 2 weeks probably.

Comment: Then what is the HASH?

Comment: @jdweng a checksum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a strange file:

- It's an XML file with a *Content* tag.
- The text of the *Content* tag is Base 64 decoded.
- The decoded data is gzip compressed.
- The decompressed data is an SVG image (with some minor mistakes).

It looks like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The content is an svg which was compressed with gz:

```
<svg viewbox="-1 -1 15 25">
  <use class="bpp" x="7" y="0" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="14" height="24" rx="0.75" ry="0.75" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(224,224,224);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.5" />
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="7" y="2" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="2" y="7" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="7" y="7" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="2" y="12" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="7" y="12" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="2" y="17" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
  <rect x="7" y="17" width="5" height="5" rx="0.25" ry="0.25" style="fill-opacity:1.0;fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0.25" />
</svg>
```

You'll have to decompress the content before you can use it.